# Is there a way to rename a chef cookbook?

Tags: chef, configuration-management, chef-server

My cookbook conflicts with a community cookbook.
There doesn't seem to be a knife option to rename or delete a cookbook.

Is there a way to delete a chef cookbook from a server or a way to rename an existing cookbook?

Answer (score 3):

I just realized what to do. (And that my question was improperly using the word recipe instead of cookbook)

So, my current state is that I have a cookbook called (for example) cookbook_name and I want to import a community cookbook of the same name.

```
cookbook_name (existing)
cookbook_name (new)
```

I figure it's easier to rename my cookbook since I wrote it and know every place I refer to the cookbook name.

Rename my old cookbook on the local filesystem:

```
mv cookbook_name new_cookbook_name
```

update the metadata file:

```
sed -i "s/cookbook_name/new_cookbook_name/" new_cookbook_name/metadata.rb
```

upload to chef server

```
knife cookbook upload new_cookbook_name
```

place the new cookbook in the cookbook home path:

```
mv ~/cookbook_name ${cookbook/path}/cookbook_name
```

and upload the new cookbook overwriting the old

```
knife cookbook upload cookbook_name
```

Now I have my old cookbook uploaded with a new name and I can upload the new cookbook and the chef server will happily overwrite the old cookbook with the new one.

Also, knife supports cookbook delete

```
knife cookbook delete COOKBOOK VERSION (options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, using `Atom` editor, you can see easily where you need to change the name of a cookbook named `base`. After renaming, deleting the one that you upload to your chef-server and done! :)

[image]